# How to take the filter value from mongodb in java code

Tags: java, mongodb

I am updating mongodb item in collection using the below command.
Now i want to take the set and filter value in java.

```
db.practice.update({"name" : "testmysqlupdate"},{$set:{"name" : "5"}})
```

I am able to take the value which need to be update i.e. name : 5, but not the conditional value i.e. "name" : "testmysqlupdate"

```
static ChangeStreamDocument<BasicDBObject> dbOb;
static MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<BasicDBObject>> cursor; 

cursor = collection.watch().fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP).iterator();

System.out.println("value of update stream us " + dbOb.getUpdateDescription().getUpdatedFields().toString());

System.out.println("Id Value is " + dbOb.getDocumentKey().toString());

document = dbOb.getUpdateDescription().getUpdatedFields().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
searchQuery.put("name", "testmysqlupdate");

BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
newDocument.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("name", "5"));

collection.update(searchQuery, newDocument);
```

Try this to update a field in MongoDB.